# Need to compare two files and delete the record only in first file if it matches

Tags: shell, unix

I need to compare two files and delete the record only in first file if its present matches. I have used the `awk` command, I'm able to print the record, but I need to remove the record from the first file which is present in both files.

Code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$0 in a{print $0}' File1 File2
```

Please anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: For me, you question is not entirely clear. Could it be reworded like this: *Remove from the first file any line which is also present in the second file*?

Answer (score 0):

> Need to compare two files and delete the record only in **first file** if
>   it matches

You need small modification

- Read your second file first store it in array `a`
- and then read your first file, if row does not exist in array `a` `print $0` from first file ( meaning record does not exist in file2 )

it can be either

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a){print $0}' File2 File1
```

Or just

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' File2 File1
```

Comment: I'm able to print the record, but i want to remove the record from file1 if the record present in file2

Comment: It will print records from first file if it  doesn't exist in second file

Answer (score 0):

**`grep`** + **`comm`** solution:

Sample `file1` content:

```
111
222
a/aa
333/
bb/b
```

---

Sample `file2` content:

```
333/
sss
ccc
a/aa
bb/b
fff
```

---

The job:

```
grep -vxf <(comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)) file1 > tmp_f && mv tmp_f file1
```

The final `file1` content:

```
111
222
```